# ItemEditEnd event for updating data provider?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

Hello guys I am new to flex. I googled a lot but I could not get any information regarding how to update data provider data. My requirement is I have a data grid with editable option set to true when I make changes over there I need to apply those changes to the data provider can any one suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Use CollectionChangeEvent

do a check on event.kind == CollectionEventKind.UPDATE
It is dispatched when a value is changed on the grid .

It has all the information about the changed object & before and after change values .